# Table Variable and Checking for Null in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query.

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[DeptIdList] AS TABLE(
    [DepartmentId] [smallint] NULL
)
GO
set nocount on

declare @department_ids DeptIdList
declare @tableContainsRecords int = 0

insert into @department_ids
values
(5), (6), (7), (8), (9)

select d.DepartmentID, d.Name, d.GroupName
  from HumanResources.Department as d
  right outer join @department_ids as di on
    d.DepartmentID = di.DepartmentID
```

I want to select specific departments if the `@department_ids` contains rows; if not the `SELECT` should return all records in the department table.

What is the easiest and optimal way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
SELECT d.DepartmentID, d.Name, d.GroupName
FROM HumanResources.Department d
WHERE DepartmentID IN (SELECT DepartmentID FROM @department_ids)
OR (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @department_ids) = 0
```